# List all Google contact groups in Android

Tags: android, sdk

I would like to list all contact groups in a Google account, and make it possible for a user to select some of the groups as "special".  When an incoming number belongs to one of the "special" groups, I want to take actions.

I can't find too many examples around this. Has someone done anything similar that you would like to share?

Answer (score 5):

You have three questions here:

1. How to enumerate the contact groups for a given account.
2. How to mark a group as special.
3. How to take action on contacts in that group.

So, going down the list...

**1. Enumerating contact groups**

The [ContactsContract.Groups](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Groups.html) table stores the list of contact groups on the system. So, you'll want to issue a query that looks like this:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI;
    Log.i(TAG, "URI: " + uri);
    String[] projection = new String[] {
           ContactsContract.Groups._ID,
           ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE
    };
    return new CursorLoader(this, uri, projection, null, null, null);
}
```

This loader will get you the list of all the groups on the system, and their database IDs.

#### How to mark a group as special

This is something your application will need to take care of. Just maintain a list of group IDs that are in your special list.

To determine whether a contact is in the "special" group, you can query the [ContactsContract.Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) table using a SQL `where` clause like the following:

```
String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID
        + "="
        + groupid
        + " AND "
        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE
        + "='"
        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
        + "'";
```

where `groupid` is the database ID of the group you've marked as special. (If you have more than one group, start adding `OR` clauses.)

(You need to check for the CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE mimetype because the [ContactsContract.Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) table is used for storing arbitrary metadata for contacts, and the meaning of the columns in that table vary by mimetype. `GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID` is simply a pointer to the column `data1`.)

**3. How to take action on contacts in that group**

This depends on what you're trying to accomplish, but in general, you'll create a broadcast receiver that listens for `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`. If the state in `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE` is listed as `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING`, then you can get the phone number by looking in `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` to find the phone number.

(There's sample code for this attached to this article: http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/)

You'll then need to check the Contacts database again to find any known contacts with that phone number. You can do this using the [ContactsContract.PhoneLookup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) table.

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,...
```

That will get you the Contact's database ID in the `ContactsContract.Contacts` table. The last step here is to match that up with the `ContactsContract.RawContacts` rows for that contact (search using the `CONTACT_ID` column), and find the set of RawContacts _IDs that represent that contact. You'll then use this to search through the group membership table, as described above.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have managed to find all groups in the phone and made them "special" in a bit more "clumsy way", but it work. The problem is now that when I catch the incoming call and shall find out if the number is in any groups i get an exception.

Comment: Don't now how to write code here formated in a nice way, else I would post source with the problem. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I found way to get correct groups by all accounts in Android:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle bundle) {
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_SUMMARY_URI;
    String[] projection = null;
    //this is correct selection for retrieving groups from android
    String selection = ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " NOT NULL AND " + 
    ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME + " NOT NULL AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED + "=0";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        selection += " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.AUTO_ADD + "=0 AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.FAVORITES + "=0";
    }

    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + " ASC";
    Loader<Cursor> loader = null;

    switch(loaderId) {
    case GROUPS_LOADER:
        loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return loader;
}
```

source: [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.4_r1/com/android/contacts/GroupListLoader.java#GroupListLoader)